# Why can't I cast an object to a constrained generic?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Given that I have the following interface and a class that implements it:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    void Feed();
}

public class Animal : IAnimal
{
    public void Feed()
    {
        // feed
    }
}
```

Why is it not possible to cast from my concrete class to a generic constrained to be IAnimal, when my Animal class implements it?

```
public class Zoo
{
    private readonly Animal animal = new Animal();

    public TAnimal GetAnimal<TAnimal>() where TAnimal : IAnimal
    {
        return (TAnimal)(this.animal); // This will not compile
    }
}
```

If I change the field type of animal to be IAnimal rather than Animal then it compiles ok:

```
public class Zoo
{
    private readonly IAnimal animal = new Animal();

    public TAnimal GetAnimal<TAnimal>() where TAnimal : IAnimal
    {
        return (TAnimal)(this.animal); // this compiles
    }
}
```

Or alternatively if I do an explicit cast to IAnimal before the cast to the generic TAnimal then this will also compile fine:

```
public class Zoo
{
    private readonly Animal animal = new Animal();

    public TAnimal GetAnimal<TAnimal>() where TAnimal : IAnimal
    {
        return (TAnimal)((IAnimal)this.animal); // this compiles
    }
}
```

So my question is - why doesn't the first version work?  Surely the compiler has enough information to know that Animal implements IAnimal, so given the constraint it would be valid to cast it to TAnimal?  Or is there something I am missing here?

Comment: And when you tell the generic to use Animal2 the code will crash anyway since Animal can't be cast into Animal2. Don't know if this is the reason, but could be. Though it will still crash even if it is IAnimal and the object itself is Animal.

Comment: What if `TAnimal` is a type of : `Human` that implements `IAnimal` but doesn't ihnerit from `Animal`...? Then the cast would be `Animal` -> `Human` so that is why compiler doesn't allow you to perform a cast.

Comment: `where TAnimal : IAnimal` thats the problem. make it `where TAnimal : Animal`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Animal` inherits from `IAnimal` and `TAnimal` doesn't inherit from `Animal`, but from `IAnimal` too. You can't cast from `A` to `B` if `B` doesn't inherit from `A`, it would be something like:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string str = (string)dt;
```

You can't do this even though `DataTable` and `string` inherit from `object`. To convert between types that aren't related by inheritance you have to define [conversion operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/85w54y0a.aspx)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary thanks, I corrected, my English is pretty poor :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have also a class `Dog`:

```
public class Dog : IAnimal 
{

}
```

If you invoke your method: `GetAnimal<TAnimal>()` with `Dog` as `TAnimal` you will have a code like this:

```
public class Zoo
{
    private readonly Animal animal = new Animal();

    public Dog GetAnimal()
    {
        return (Dog)this.animal;
    }
}
```

Of course `Dog` does not inherit from `Animal` so the casting is wrong.

Then you have your second example:

```
public class Zoo
{
    private readonly IAnimal animal = new Animal();

    public Dog GetAnimal()
    {
        return (Dog)this.animal;
    }
}
```

`Dog` is implementing `IAnimal`, so this will compile. It will however throw a `InvalidCastException` in runtime. The same thing applies to the double casting in your third example:

```
public class Zoo
{
    private readonly Animal animal = new Animal();

    public Dog GetAnimal()
    {
        return (Dog)(IAnimal)this.animal;
    }
}
```

You can cast from `Animal` to `IAnimal` and from `IAnimal` to `Dog`, however it will throw `InvalidCastException`.